# CSS Grid with an additional wrapper in the middle

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-grid

I want to use CSS Grid's grid-template-areas.

But the problem is that the CMS I'm using is adding lots of additional wrappers.
Is there a way to ignore extra wrappers? since it is messing up the nice grid areas...

I'm trying to override css grid's auto-placement mechanism. 
So any div that is in the middle, and wasn't assigned a specific grid-area, will appear at the end of the grid, and wouldn't mess with the grid itself.

I created an example of the problem here -
https://codepen.io/shaal/pen/qPvQWW

You can see that because of the extra wrapper, the 'sidebar' element is not assigned to the areas I wanted it to be.

HTML

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "sidebar content content" "sidebar content content" "footer footer footer";
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  height: 180px;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS GRID</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item header">Header</div>
  <div class="cms-annoying-wrapper">
    <div class="item sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="item content">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not target the CMS wrapper as the grid item instead of the child? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VMRVWm

Comment: Thank you. I updated the code to reflect the problematic placement of the wrapper.

Comment: Can you target the CMS-generated wrapper with your CSS?

Comment: Not sure if that what you meant, I can target the wrapper in the css like this ->     .css-annoying-wrapper { border: 3px solid red; }

Answer (score 34):

Grid Layout Module Level 2 - [Subgrids](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid-2/#subgrids) are supposed to solve this problem.

---

In the meantime, there is a workaround:

### **[display: contents](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#valdef-display-contents)** ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents))

From [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents):

> `display: contents` causes an element's children to appear as if they
>   were direct children of the element's parent, ignoring the element
>   itself. This can be useful when a wrapper element should be ignored
>   when using CSS grid or similar layout techniques.

So in your scenario you could simply add the rule:

```
.cms-annoying-wrapper {
  display: contents;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 580px;
}
.cms-annoying-wrapper {
  display: contents;
}


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header header header"
    "sidebar content content"
    "sidebar content content"
    "footer footer footer";
}

.item {
  color: white;
  padding: 1.5em 0;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.header {
  background: #0d6;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #f00;
}

.content {
  background: #d60;
}

.footer {
  background: #60d;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  height: 180px;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS GRID</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item header">Header</div>
  <div class="cms-annoying-wrapper">
    <div class="item sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="item content">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

### [Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/bYNMNN) (firefox)

Comment: Only works for me in Chrome and Firefox. Is there currently a workaround available for Edge to ignore the wrapper element?

Answer (score 1):

If using the unwrap jQuery function to remove this div is not a problem for you I would use it.

```
$(".sidebar").unwrap(".cms-annoying-wrapper");
```

Otherwise in plain JS :
https://plainjs.com/javascript/manipulation/unwrap-a-dom-element-35/

Comment: I'm trying to avoid hacks through Javascript, and get into the clean methods of css grid

Comment: I understand and you are right to avoid the use of Javascript. I put this answer in case there are no other option. The option of @Michael_B is indeed what you are looking for! Happy coding.