# How can I make my grid layout sections to span 4 columns each?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am attempting a grid layout, but can't seem to get the left, middle and right to span 4 columns each, along the same row in a 12 column grid.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
- Header                                                                -
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
- Nav                                                                   -
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
- Banner
- Banner                                                                -
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------  ----------------------- ------------------------
-                      - -                     - -                      -
-   left               - -  middle             - -    right             -
-                      - -                     - -                      -
-                      - -                     - -                      -
------------------------ ----------------------- ------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
-            footer                  -           footer                 -
-                                    -                                  -
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

header {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  background: #3bbced;
  padding: 30px;
}

nav {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  background: #3bbced;
  padding: 30px;
}

main {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  background: grey;
}

.span-12 {
  grid-column-start: span 13;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  background: red;
  padding: 30px;
}

.left {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 5;
  background: green;
  padding: 30px;
}

.middle {
  grid-column-start: 5;
  grid-column-end: 9;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 5;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 30px;
}

.right {
  grid-column-start: 10;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 5;
  background: orange;
  padding: 30px;
}

footer {
  grid-column: span 12;
  grid-row: 9 / 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="logo">Header</header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="/">Menu</a>
      <a href="/">Book</a>
      <a href="/">About</a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <article class="span-12">Ipsum</article>
    <section class="left">Ipsum</section>
    <section class="middle">Ipsum</section>
    <section class="right">Ipsum</section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="footer-col-left">small logo</div>
    <div class="footer-col-right">copywrite</div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Grid with an additional wrapper in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46856825/css-grid-with-an-additional-wrapper-in-the-middle)

Comment: Why is your footer all the way down on the 9th row?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `display:grid` set on an element this this will only affect it's immediate children. In your case the grid will take effect on the element `main` since this is the direct child of `container`.

If you want the grid to affect the left,middle,right as well as the footer columns you would either have to pull them out of their respective parents or you can set main and footer to have the same grid as it's parent.

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: inherit;
```

I don't know if you will be using the grid on container in any other way than presented in this question. But you might consider not using a grid on container and just putting it on the elements that needs columns.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

header {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  background: #3bbced;
  padding: 30px;
}

nav {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  background: #3bbced;
  padding: 30px;
}

main {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  background: grey;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: inherit;
}
footer{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: inherit;
}

.span-12 {
  grid-column-start: span 13;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  background: red;
  padding: 30px;
}

.left {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 5;
  background: green;
  padding: 30px;
}

.middle {
  grid-column-start: 5;
  grid-column-end: 9;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 5;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 30px;
}

.right {
  grid-column-start: 10;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 5;
  background: orange;
  padding: 30px;
}

footer {
  grid-column: span 12;
  grid-row: 9 / 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="logo">Header</header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="/">Menu</a>
      <a href="/">Book</a>
      <a href="/">About</a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <article class="span-12">Ipsum</article>
    <section class="left">Ipsum</section>
    <section class="middle">Ipsum</section>
    <section class="right">Ipsum</section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="footer-col-left">small logo</div>
    <div class="footer-col-right">copywrite</div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap left-middle-right on a div or section and try this css

```
display : grid;
grid-template-areas: "a a a";
width: 100%;
```